# Using the @ symbol in Strings

Tags: java, string, variables

In several open source java projects, I have seen the use of the @ symbol in string variables, what does this do?

For example, I have seen it in an application that has its version number stored in a String instance, e.g:

```
public static final String APP_VERSION = "@VERSION@";
```

Comment: The `@VERSION@` will be see seend as a variable as opposed to just a string called "VERSION". In the build process, `@VERSION@` would be substituted with a version number. If the string was just `"VERSION"` then it wouldn't be substituted. It would appear to be "just another string".

Comment: another common pattern is `$Id$` etc, use by SVN at _commit_ time, rather than build time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is used for the build scripts as marker to replace these string with build time information, such as the real version. The real information is usually taken from a property file or from timestamp.

Comment: Ah, so in the build script, how would you define what to replace it with? I am using an xml file to compile the project.

Comment: That's different from tool to tool. in Ant see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html, for Maven see https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/

Answer (score 4):

Putting `@` in a string doesn't do anything special (with respect to Java). That example looks peculiar though. It's possible that the value is substituted with the real version number by a build script before compiling. It's also possible that the string is doing something else entirely.